# multitouch in WPF Not working

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, multi-touch

I'm new to multi touch programming. im using windows7, VS-2010 and WPF to develop.I follow the tutorial in this link:

http://surfacedeveloper.blogspot.in/2009/10/multi-touch-in-wpf-40-and-vs2010.html

here i don't have the property **ManipulationMode="All"**. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManipulationMode` seemed to be a `UIElement` property in .NET 4.0 beta 1. I guess it was what now is [IsManipulationEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismanipulationenabled.aspx).